# troubling rebasing branch with merge conflics

Tags: git, git-rebase

I am trying to rebase my branch with development. This was a long ticket and I probably should a rebased a few times during development. Anyway, at one point I checked in my current progress. then I did a bunch of the rest of the work. Now I wanted to run:

```
git rebase development
```

Got a couple of merge conflicts and thats fine. The problem is for some reason all the files without conflicts are rolled back to that first commit.

```
➥  git rebase development
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: initial check in for issue code widget <<<< I THINK THIS IS THE OFFENDING PART
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
```

If you understand what is going on, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically git "replays" your commits from your topic branch one by one on top of the other branch you specified, in this case, `development`. I presume you are seeing conflicts from the very first commit(s) ? In that case, then yes, git will stop and at that stage you will see conflicted files, plus the files without conflicts *only from the first commit*

Once you resolve the conflict(s), git will continue replaying subsequent commits, and so on, until you reach the merged state where you have all your topic branch commits on top of development